# Getting album art for all music files

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediastore

I am trying to fetch the album art of all the songs present on the phone. I am using MediaStore to fetch all the songs title,artist etc. How should I fetch album art ? I tried using MediaMetaDataRetriever but getting confused how to use it for multiple files. Can anyone please tweak this code?

Activity class:

```
public void getSongList() {
    // retrieve song info
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null,
            null);
    metaRetriver.setDataSource(MainActivity.this,musicUri); // now how to loop over this

    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(AudioColumns.ARTIST);

        // add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
        } while (musicCursor.moveToNext());

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the album id, which you can get from that same cursor, you can query a different URI for the cover art path. see below for an example of approximately how I do it:

```
private static String getCoverArtPath(Context context, long androidAlbumId) {
    String path = null;
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?",
            new String[]{Long.toString(androidAlbumId)},
            null);
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            path = c.getString(0);
        }
        c.close();
    }
    return path;
}
```

You could get a Map of all album art by id using something like this (untested)

```
private static Map<Long, String> getCoverArtPaths(Context context) {
    String HashMap<Long, String> map = new HashMap<Long, String>();
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
            null,
            null,
            null);
    if (c != null) {
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            map.add(c.getLong(0), c.getString(1));
        }
        c.close();
    }
    // returns a mapping of Album ID => art file path
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt for the answer. I have posted my answer above. But I am getting a delay of 2-3 sec for fetching the album art for around 300 songs on my device on create . Is there any way I can speed it up?

Comment: Yes, you can get them all in one query. You could remove the WHERE param, and loop through all the albums, getting their album art, or build a WHERE IN clause, using your album IDs. Keep in mind if you're going to bind params with '?'s, you're limited to 999 of them.

Comment: Can you please give me the code how to do it. It takes a lot of time to fetch the album art . I tried using Async Task also . But still loading of album art takes time.

Comment: see edit - you should be able to get a map, then do a simple lookup for your path. the new Map should be queried in 1 transaction so should be much faster.

Comment: Tried your solution too . But it doesnt make any change . I guess the problem is with the 4 lines: String pathId=map.get(thisId);
    metaRetriver.setDataSource(pathId);
    try { 
     art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
     BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     opt.inScaled=true;
     songImage = BitmapFactory .decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length,opt);
    }

Comment: Why are you using a MetaDataRetriever? My solution should give you paths to the album art. Decoding them might take some time, but why would you need to decode 300 all at once? Only decode them as they are rendered, or at least in the background and show them to the user as they are ready.

Comment: I am using metaDetaRetriever to just set the data source with the path . Is that slow ? Or should I use something else? and now I am fetching the album art in adapter so its faster now. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I got it working like this. Hope it helps someone :)

```
 public void getSongList() {
    // retrieve song info

    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null,
            null);


    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(AudioColumns.ARTIST);
        int column_index = musicCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

        // add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String pathId = musicCursor.getString(column_index);
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "path id=" + pathId);

            metaRetriver.setDataSource(pathId);
            try { 
                art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
                Options opt = new Options();
                opt.inSampleSize = 2;
                songImage = BitmapFactory .decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length,opt);
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            { imgAlbumArt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY); 
            }

            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist,songImage));
            //              if(songImage!=null)
            //              {
            //              songImage.recycle();
            //              }
        } while (musicCursor.moveToNext());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Fast rendering**

If you are using recylerview, listview to render song list and it is making slow due to getting album art from song path then you can first check if ImageView has already background image set then don't process anything. It will reduce lot of processing and make scrolling fast even if song list is very large. I was facing same problem. I just did same as mentioned and recyclerview rendering with album art became smooth otherwise it was getting stuck during scroll.
My be this will help someone.

My code for recyclerview:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            if (holder instanceof MusicAdapter.MusicViewHolder) {
                MusicAdapter.MusicViewHolder vh = (MusicAdapter.MusicViewHolder) holder;
                vh.tvTitle.setText(musicList.get(position).title.toString());
                vh.tvArtistAndAblum.setText(musicList.get(position).artist.toString() + " | " + musicList.get(position).album.toString());
                Drawable background = vh.ivMusicIcon.getBackground();
                if(background == null) {
                    String pathId = musicList.get(position).path;
                    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                    metaRetriver.setDataSource(pathId);
                    try {
                        byte[] art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
                        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        opt.inSampleSize = 2;
                        Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length,opt);
                        BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), songImage);
                        vh.ivMusicIcon.setBackground(ob);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        vh.ivMusicIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.compact_disc);
                    }

                }

            } else if (holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
                FooterViewHolder vh = (FooterViewHolder) holder;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```